# Strange error while trying manual authentication in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel 5.2 so now I'm trying manual authentication but I got this error:

```
1/1
ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 114:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\myblog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 378 and defined
```

Here's my form:

```
<form method="post" action='login'>
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input name="username" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input name="password" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

and Here's my route:

```
Route::post('login', 'ProfilesController@login');
```

and here's my login method:

```
public function login(Request $request){

        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended();
        }else{
            return "Something went wrong";
        }

    }
```

My table is 'users' and it has 'username' and 'password'
Have any idea how to fix this?
Notice: I added use Auth; in the top of my controller

Comment: Can you provide the class defintion for your `App\User` class?

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}

That's all in my App\User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `App\User` class must implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable` contract.  This is because the repository method has it typehinted as such.  The default user implementation (at least now at 5.2) does, indirectly by extending `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`.

You can find information about the `Authenticable` contract in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) entry on authentication.  From that link, the contract looks like this:

```
namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Auth;

interface Authenticatable {

    public function getAuthIdentifierName();
    public function getAuthIdentifier();
    public function getAuthPassword();
    public function getRememberToken();
    public function setRememberToken($value);
    public function getRememberTokenName();

}
```

Fortunately, Laravel provides a trait in `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticable` that provides a lot of this functionality for you, so all you should need to do to satisfy this error is `use` that trait, which you can do the same way as default Laravel 5.2 does (by inheriting from the same class):

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticable;

class User extends Authenticable
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great it works !
But I have a simple question now everytime I enter the correct username and password it returns Something went wrong
When I entered the password for the user I'm trying to login with I used bcrypt function, should I use bcrybt for the password given from the form?

Comment: You shouldn't have to use any hashing function by default. See `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`.  This is a trait that is used by the default `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` class